# Does Xubuntu keep a log of all USB devices ever connected to the system?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, logging, xubuntu

What I specifically need is a log that shows the exact time and date a USB device was plugged in or removed.

Example :

```
14:40 USB DEVICE X WAS MOUNTED
14:43 USB DEVICE X WAS REMOVED
02:12 USB DEVICE Y WAS MOUNTED
```

Is this possible in Xubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

You will find information on connected and disconnected USB devices in `/var/log/dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` (at least on a Debian-based system like (X)Ubuntu). `syslog` will be more helpful for you, since it contains the actual date and time, not just the seconds since the system was started.

If you're only interested in recent activity, you will probably get away with searching the most recent logfile:

```
grep ' usb ' /var/log/syslog
```

If that doesn't suffice, you will have to unzip `/var/log/syslog.*.gz` (not to `/var/log`, though!) and search them as well.